# Altair: how can I style lines differently in a facet grid, based on their max value?

Tags: python, data-visualization, facet, altair

I am trying to create a facet plot to compare the reaction times of subjects from a sleep deprivation study. The data come from the `sleepstudy` dataset, available in the `pydataset` package.

By using `altair.condition` I am able to style the lines differently. The problem is that I am not getting the result I would like to obtain. I aim to highlight in orange only the lines that exceeds 400 (ms) at least once, namely the subjects 308, 332, and 337 in the chart below.

The `alt.condition` I am using in the code below seems to test only the first datum of the `df.Reaction` Pandas Series.

I am using altair `4.0.1`.

```py
import altair as alt
from pydataset import data

df = data('sleepstudy')

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('Days:O', title=''),
    y=alt.Y('Reaction:Q', title='', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(200, 450))),
    # How do I test for the condition: is max(reaction) > 400 ms at least once during the study?
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.datum['Reaction'] > 300,
        alt.value('orange'),
        alt.value('darkgray')
    ),
    facet=alt.Facet('Subject:O', columns=3, title=''),
).properties(
    title='Reaction times (ms) for sleep-deprived subjects over 10 days',
    width=200,
    height=100
)
```

[image: facet grid from a dataset about a sleep deprivation study]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a [joinaggregate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/joinaggregate.html) to compute the maximum value within each pane, and then color based on this maximum:

```
import altair as alt
from pydataset import data

df = data('sleepstudy')

alt.Chart(df).transform_joinaggregate(
    maxReaction='max(Reaction)',
    groupby=['Subject']
).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('Days:O', title=''),
    y=alt.Y('Reaction:Q', title='', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(200, 450))),
    # How do I test for the condition: is max(reaction) > 400 ms at least once during the study?
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.datum['maxReaction'] > 400,
        alt.value('orange'),
        alt.value('darkgray')
    ),
    facet=alt.Facet('Subject:O', columns=3, title=''),
).properties(
    title='Reaction times (ms) for sleep-deprived subjects over 10 days',
    width=200,
    height=100
)
```

[image]